# rbenv shell not command

Tags: ruby, installation, rbenv

rbenv installed. but rbenv shell not command.

```
ationtekiMacBook-Air:~ dation$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.0.0-p247 (set by /Users/dation/.ruby-version)
dationtekiMacBook-Air:~ dation$ rbenv version
2.0.0-p247 (set by /Users/dation/.ruby-version)
dationtekiMacBook-Air:~ dation$ rbenv shell
rbenv: no such command `shell'
```

---

```
ationtekiMacBook-Air:~ dation$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is this note in rbenv's README (see [Installation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-shell)) about the `shell` command:

> Note that you'll need rbenv's shell integration enabled (step 3 of the installation instructions) in order to use this command.

Step 3 is:

> Add rbenv init to your shell to enable shims and autocompletion.
>
> ```
> $ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
> ```
>
> Same as in previous step, use ~/.profile on Ubuntu, ~/.zshrc for Zsh.

Did you follow that instruction?

Answer (score 5):

one gotya that I haven't seen posted on the internet is that in .bash_profile, you have ensure that

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

is placed before

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Otherwise the shell will try to run rbenv init before it can be found.

Reversing these two lines will cause both problems described by the OP;

`ruby -v` not showing the version that was set by rbenv

`rbvenv shell` returning "rbenv: no such command `shell’".

Don't ask how I know!

I today opened an issue in Github to propose an update to sstephenson's already awesome documentation.

Comment: On my system, Antergos (Arch for the weak of heart), this has to be in .bashrc, not .bash_profile, so there is also the possiblity that you have the proper lines in the wrong file but the right order.